# Proper potato watering time

Tags: watering, potatoes

One of the traditional ways potato's are often grown is by slowly piling up dirt and straw around them as they reach around 7-8 inches above the last layer.

I am wondering when would be the best time to water at a time when the are ready for another layer. Should i water them and then put on another layer or put on a layer and then water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would water them first since water can wash away the hill.

You see, the plant doesn't need any water in the hill. The hill is strictly for preventing sunlight from getting to the young potatoes while they are growing.

An alternative to hilling is to stack boxes or tires around the plant and filling the stack with straw to stop light from reaching the new potatoes. No water needed and it's a lot less work than the careful digging needed to harvest the potatoes.